# Updating model/collection from React component

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I see a lot of examples using React with backbone, there is however some things that are still somewhat unclear to me. In nearly all examples they show how you can get your component to listen to a model or collection and update the view accordingly, this seems pretty straightforward, you can use the Backbone Mixin or you can setup some event listeners in "componentDidMount()".

What is unclear to me is how to handle the other way, ie when a user writes in some input field, I then want to set this same value on my model, which ultimately is what i validate and then save on the server.

With simple forms this is also pretty straightforward, you can have a callback for the onChange event, example:

```
return <div><input type="text" onChange={this.setPrice} /></div>
```

All good, in the setPrice function I can now do something like:

```
this.props.myModel.set('price', e.target.value);
```

This works, but two things that immediately strike me:
The set method will be called on the model every single key event, since Reacts "onChange" actually executes on every key event, when you type in the textbox.

My second concern is, this works good for simple forms, however we have forms that have upwards 30-40 different input fields, having an onChange event on all of these input boxes, checkboxes and what have you seems counterproductive.

Right now, we have a databinding in our Backbone Views that simply sets whatever the user types on these input fields on the model, this does not seem to be the way togo in React though since what would be updated if you use something like ReactLink is the properties inside "state" on the Component, not properties directly on the model.

Is there a best practice here, or is this "marriage" between React and Backbone simply not meant to be? It would seem as if you would need to somehow map each input field to a specific property on the model. I am not sure if this is a good thing todo with React.

Thanks

Comment: I'm just learning how to use React too, but the solution that I'm leaning towards at the moment is to bubble up that state out of the DOM elements and into the model using the [two-way helper](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html), then on form submit essentially fire off an action which updates the Backbone models all in one go.

Comment: Where is your `setState` function being called within your component?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `setPrice` method `onBlur` instead of `onChange` so that you will update the state when the user clicks or tabs out of the field.

This is more efficient for longer forms in my opinion as you are guaranteed that the user will tab or click to the next field.